# Missing factor 1/2 when using generalized Stokes theorem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, differential-geometry, topological-phase, wilson-loop

I'm doing the following homework question:

> By invoking Stokes' theorem, according to which the integral of a
> vector field (which equals the field strength) over any two-dimension
> surface S that is bounded by that closed path (see 1.57),
> $$\Phi(x_1;x_1)=\exp\left[\oint-ieA_\mu(x)\mathrm d
>  x^\mu\right]=\exp\left[\int_S-\tfrac{1}{2}ie F_{\mu\nu}\mathrm{ d}
> S^{\mu\nu}\right]$$ where $\int_S F_{\mu\nu}\mathrm d S^{\mu\nu}$
> denotes twice the total electromagnetic flux through the surface $S$.
> The quantity $\Phi(x_1;x_2)$  is known as a non-integrable phase
> factor [305].

Equation 1.57 refers to the vector version of Stokes' theorem i.e. $\int_S \mathbf B\cdot \mathrm d \mathbf S=\oint_C\mathbf A\cdot \mathrm d \mathbf l$. Using this formula naively I'm able to find the answer but I'm not sure how to handle the fact that the dot product is using the Minkowski metric. I want to solve this using the theory of one-forms because it's also a nice practice. To do this I'm using the following definitions (which might be wrong)

\begin{align}
A&=A_\mu\mathrm d x^\mu\\
F&=\mathrm d A\\
(\mathrm d A)_{\mu\nu}&=\partial_\mu A_\nu-\partial_\nu A_\mu \\
\mathrm d A&=(\mathrm d A)_{\mu\nu}\,\mathrm d x^\mu\wedge\mathrm d x^\nu 
\end{align}

Then I get the following
\begin{align}
\oint A_\mu\mathrm d x^\mu&=\int_{\partial S}A\\
&=\int_S\mathrm d A&\text{(Generalized Stokes)}\\
&=\int_S F\\
&=\int_S F_{\mu\nu}\,\mathrm d x^\mu\wedge\mathrm d x^\nu\\
&=\int_S F_{\mu\nu}\,\mathrm d S^{\mu\nu}
\end{align}
So I get an overall factor 1/2 wrong. Where does this factor come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A=A_\nu\, dx^{\nu}$ then
$$
dA= \partial_{\mu} A_{\nu} \,dx^{\mu} \wedge dx^{\nu}\\
= \frac 12 (\partial_{\mu} A_{\nu}-\partial_{\nu} A_{\mu})dx^{\mu} \wedge dx^{\nu}\\
= \frac 12 F_{\mu\nu} dx^{\mu} \wedge dx^{\nu}
$$

Comment: Thanks that explains the discrepancy. On wikipedia's article for the exterior derivative https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative#In_terms_of_local_coordinates I found the definition $(\mathrm d\omega)_{\mu\nu}=\partial_\mu\omega_\nu-\partial_\nu\omega_\mu$. Does that definition agree with the one you're using? Or are those two different conventions?

Comment: It's not a notation that I would use precisely because of the factor of two. I Always write $\omega= \frac 1{p!} \omega_{i_1\ldots i_p} dx^{{i_1}}\cdots dx^{i_p}$, where the $p!$ eliminates the overcounting.